# QGIS 2.0 cannot open TIFF

Tags: raster, qgis-2, geotiff-tiff

I've just installed QGIS 2.0 on my Windows 7 computer. I'm trying to open a raster and the system reports this message:

```
Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: where did the tiff image come from?

Comment: from the training package of qgis

Comment: In Qgis Dufour windows standallone 32 bits I have no problem opening a either a tiff (in georeferencer) or a geotiff (add raster Layer).

Comment: i'm on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: I've tried installing 1.8 and I had no problem on the same PC

Comment: I have the same problem. The error occurs when the tif file is compressed. (At least it occurs with compress=deflate).  Only occurs in 64bit as far as I can tell.